# Как сменить платежную систему в sale.order.ajax?

Tags: ajax, битрикс

Всем привет !
Пытаюсь сменить платежную систему(сбербанк) в sale.order.ajax. В админке создал точную копию существующей ПС. В файлах шаблона sale.order.ajax, везде где нашел, поменял ID на новые. Но когда пытаюсь оформить заказ консоль выдает ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь лог консоли:

```
www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-KHQPN3Q:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
personal.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
personal.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16720 m.fn.init(2)
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16720 m.fn.init(2)
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16720 m.fn.init(1)
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16658 Uncaught ReferenceError: ymaps is not defined
    at init_geo (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16658)
    at Object.success (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16726)
    at j (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16248)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16248)
    at x (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250)
init.js?id=cl1rksj8:1 [Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
searchRule @ init.js?id=cl1rksj8:1
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16617 m.fn.init(1)
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16617 m.fn.init(1)
https.embed.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: e.debugConsole is not a function
    at Object.s.init (https.embed.js:1)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https.embed.js:1)
    at t.value (https.embed.js:1)
    at o.value (https.embed.js:1)
    at t.<anonymous> (https.embed.js:1)
    at t.value (https.embed.js:1)
    at MessagePort.r.port1.onmessage (https.embed.js:1)
personal.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://dantonehome.com/local/templates/dantone_en/css/style.css.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:28031 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    </script>
    
        
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    
    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->
    <script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-KHQPN3Q');</script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="/bitrix/js/main/core/css/core.css?15317736523963" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/bitrix/js/ui/fonts/opensans/ui.font.opensans.css?15792501952003" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/bitrix/js/main/popup/dist/main.popup.bundle.css?159134981426339" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/bitrix/js/main/core/css/core_date.css?153177365210289" type="text/css"  rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/bitrix/panel/main/popup.css?153177365323084" type="text/css"  data-template-style="true"  rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">if(!window.BX)window.BX={};if(!window.BX.message)window.BX.message=function(mess){if(typeof mess==='object'){for(let i in mess) {BX.message[i]=mess[i];} return true;}};</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.BX||top.BX).message({'JS_CORE_LOADING':'Loading...','JS_CORE_WINDOW_CLOSE':'Close','JS_CORE_WINDOW_EXPAND':'Expand','JS_CORE_WINDOW_NARROW':'Restore','JS_CORE_WINDOW_SAVE':'Save','JS_CORE_WINDOW_CANCEL':'Cancel','JS_CORE_H':'h','JS_CORE_M':'m','JS_CORE_S':'s','JS_CORE_NO_DATA':'- No data -','JSADM_AI_HIDE_EXTRA':'Hide extra items','JSADM_AI_ALL_NOTIF':'All notifications','JSADM_AUTH_REQ':'Authentication is required!','JS_CORE_WINDOW_AUTH':'Log In','JS_CORE_IMAGE_FULL':'Full size','JS_CORE_WINDOW_CONTINUE':'Continue'});</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/bitrix/js/main/core/core.js?1591349818544313"></script>

<script>BX.setJSList(['/bitrix/js/main/core/core_ajax.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core_promise.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/promise/js/promise.js','/bitrix/js/main/loadext/loadext.js','/bitrix/js/main/loadext/extension.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/promise/js/promise.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/find/js/find.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/includes/js/includes.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/matches/js/matches.js','/bitrix/js/ui/polyfill/closest/js/closest.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/fill/main.polyfill.fill.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/find/js/find.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/matches/js/matches.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/core/dist/polyfill.bundle.js','/bitrix/js/main/core/core.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/intersectionobserver/js/intersectionobserver.js','/bitrix/js/main/lazyload/dist/lazyload.bundle.js','/bitrix/js/main/polyfill/core/dist/polyfill.bundle.js','/bitrix/js/main/parambag/dist/parambag.bundle.js']);
BX.setCSSList(['/bitrix/js/main/core/css/core.css','/bitrix/js/main/lazyload/dist/lazyload.bundle.css','/bitrix/js/main/parambag/dist/parambag.bundle.css']);</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.BX||top.BX).message({'YANDEX_KEY':'trnsl.1.1.20170718T163026Z.c2c445683d41ca19.24f04e6596fcad16473aa3ff44e79ed36067c13a'});(window.BX||top.BX).message({'TRANS_FROM':'','TRANS_TO':'','CORRECT_FROM':'','CORRECT_TO':''});</script>
<script type="text/javascript">(window.BX||top.BX).message({'AMPM_MODE':'2'});(window.BX||top.BX).message({'MONTH_1':'January','MONTH_2':'February','MONTH_3':'March','MONTH_4':'April','MONTH_5':'May','MONTH_6':'June','MONTH_7':'July','MONTH_8':'August','MONTH_9':'September','MONTH_10':'October','MONTH_11':'November','MONTH_12':'December','MONTH_1_S':'January','MONTH_2_S':'February','MONTH_3_S':'March','MONTH_4_S':'April','MONTH_5_S':'May','MONTH_6_S':'June','MONTH_7_S':'July','MONTH_8_S':'August','MONTH_9_S':'September','MONTH_10_S':'October','MONTH_11_S':'November','MONTH_12_S':'December','MON_1':'Jan','MON_2':'Feb','MON_3':'Mar','MON_4':'Apr','MON_5':'May','MON_6':'Jun','MON_7':'Jul','MON_8':'Aug','MON_9':'Sep','MON_10':'Oct','MON_11':'Nov','MON_12':'Dec','DAY_OF_WEEK_0':'Sunday','DAY_OF_WEEK_1':'Monday','DAY_OF_WEEK_2':'Tuesday','DAY_OF_WEEK_3':'Wednesday','DAY_OF_WEEK_4':'Thursday','DAY_OF_WEEK_5'
?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:28033 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'REDIRECT_URL' of undefined
    at Object.success (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:28033)
    at j (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16248)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16248)
    at x (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250)
    at XMLHttpRequest.b (?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250)
success @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:28033
j @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16248
fireWith @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16248
x @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250
b @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
send @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250
ajax @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:16250
submitOrder @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:28026
onclick @ ?bitrix_include_areas=N&clear_cache=Y:27739
```

Answer (score 0):

укажите в настройках sale.order.ajax дефолтный шаблон, либо тот где вы не вносили изменения.

> везде где нашел, поменял ID на новые
> -это делать в шаблоне не стоит

По настройке платёжных систем всё тут https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=42&CHAPTER_ID=03076